# [Flash Builder] Disable security sandbox warnings (not fix them)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I am building a project where I use an external API loaded from the web, and I also load files locally. As I understand it, I cannot load both local and external files without causing a security sandbox error.

Once I open the API it seems to try and listen to mouse events and such, and causes a security sandbox error every single frame.

Its really annoying since I am trying to trace some debug outputs but I can't read them as they get overwhelmed by the error messages.

I know I cannot fix it, but I would simply like to disable these warnings. 
Is there any way?

(please don't post solutions to fix the error, I tried all of them)

I just want to disable the messages.

Here is the error message:

> *** Security Sandbox Violation *** SecurityDomain
>   'http://agi.armorgames.com/assets/agi/AGI.swf' tried to access
>   incompatible context
>   'file:///D|/Flash/Projects/LastChapel/bin%2Ddebug/LastChapel.swf'

Comment: Obviously, you didn't try them all but, yeah I won't post the solution since you don't want it.

Comment: I tried a lot of things, but if you think your solution might work, go ahead. I am just tired of getting all the same obvious answers that didn't work.

Comment: put this on the first line in your code Security.allowInsecureDomain("\*");Security.allowDomain("\*");

Comment: I already did don't worry. It still changes nothing.

Comment: Put crossdomain.xml file on the root of the domain. after that you can access the data of that domain into swf.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change flash global settings ? Right click on the animation and change trusted locations settings to add your URLs.

There is some info here : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlayer/LSM/WS6aa5ec234ff3f285139dc56112e3786b68c-7ff0.html#WS6aa5ec234ff3f285139dc56112e3786b68c-7feb

Comment: Yes I did, all my drives are allowed as well as the url of the swf I am loading